# Как расширить базовый абстрактный класс реализацией интерфейса?

Tags: c#, наследование, интерфейс, aspnetboilerplate

Вопрос и приведённые ниже примеры кода относятся к Asp.Net Boilerplate, но мне кажется что это не суть важно и применимо к теме наследования в принципе.
Имеется иерархия классов и интерфейсов: 
[image: Интерфейсы и классы]

Исходный код интерфейсов и классов доступен на [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/tree/dev/src/Abp/Application/Services). Задача состоит в добавлении поиска к базовому классу [AsyncCrudAppService](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Application/Services/AsyncCrudAppService.cs). Для этого был создан новый абстрактный класс AsyncCrudAppServiceEx, который наследуется от AsyncCrudAppService и реализует нужный функционал, а также создан интерфейс ISearchService. Так как в контроллер передаётся именно интерфейс, то в ICompanyAppService был добавлен и ISearchService. Всё работает и нас стороне MVC контроллера я могу выполнять поиск, но у меня не получается добавить интерфейс ISearchService в мой базовый абстрактный класс - ошибка:

> Ошибка    CS0311  Тип "Abp.Application.Services.Dto.EntityDto<System.Guid>" не может быть использован как параметр типа "TGetInput" в универсальном типе или методе "AsyncCrudAppServiceEx<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput>". Нет преобразования неявной ссылки из "Abp.Application.Services.Dto.EntityDto<System.Guid>" в "MyApp.Services.ISearchService<ProcimMS.Companies.Dto.GetAllCompaniesDto>".

Другими словами... Создаю универсальный абстрактный класс AsyncCrudAppServiceEx, наследую его от универсального абстрактного AsyncCrudAppService и добавляю в него нужный функционал. Создаю универсальный интерфейс ISearchService и добавляю его в CompanyAppService. Всё работает - на стороне контроллера методы видны и работают. Но если я добавляю интерфейс в универсальный абстрактный класс AsyncCrudAppServiceEx, то в CompanyAppService появляется вышеуказанная ошибка.

Предполагаю, что это происходит из-за того, что классы и интерфейсы являются универсальными (generic), но в чём конкретно моя ошибка не могу понять.

Как правильно расширить функционал абстрактного класса [AsyncCrudAppService](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Application/Services/AsyncCrudAppService.cs)?

---

public abstract class AsyncCrudAppService

```js
    namespace Abp.Application.Services {

        public abstract class AsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput>
        : AsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput, EntityDto<TPrimaryKey>>
            where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
            where TEntityDto : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
            where TUpdateInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
            where TGetInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey> {

            protected AsyncCrudAppService(IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> repository)
                : base(repository) { }
        }

        public abstract class AsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput, TDeleteInput>
           : CrudAppServiceBase<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput>,
            IAsyncCrudAppService<TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput, TDeleteInput>
               where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
               where TEntityDto : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
               where TUpdateInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
               where TGetInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
               where TDeleteInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey> {

            public IAsyncQueryableExecuter AsyncQueryableExecuter { get; set; }

            protected AsyncCrudAppService(IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> repository)
                :base(repository) {
                AsyncQueryableExecuter = NullAsyncQueryableExecuter.Instance;
            }

            public virtual async Task<TEntityDto> Get(TGetInput input) {
                CheckGetPermission();

                var entity = await GetEntityByIdAsync(input.Id);
                return MapToEntityDto(entity);
            }

            public virtual async Task<PagedResultDto<TEntityDto>> GetAll(TGetAllInput input) {

                CheckGetAllPermission();

                var query = CreateFilteredQuery(input);

                var totalCount = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.CountAsync(query);

                query = ApplySorting(query, input);
                query = ApplyPaging(query, input);

                var entities = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

                return new PagedResultDto<TEntityDto>(
                    totalCount,
                    entities.Select(MapToEntityDto).ToList()
                );
            }

            public virtual async Task<TEntityDto> Create(TCreateInput input) {

                CheckCreatePermission();

                var entity = MapToEntity(input);

                await Repository.InsertAsync(entity);
                await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

                return MapToEntityDto(entity);
            }

            public virtual async Task<TEntityDto> Update(TUpdateInput input) {
                CheckUpdatePermission();

                var entity = await GetEntityByIdAsync(input.Id);

                MapToEntity(input, entity);
                await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

                return MapToEntityDto(entity);
            }

            public virtual Task Delete(TDeleteInput input) {

                CheckDeletePermission();

                return Repository.DeleteAsync(input.Id);
            }

            protected virtual Task<TEntity> GetEntityByIdAsync(TPrimaryKey id) {
                return Repository.GetAsync(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

AsyncCrudAppServiceEx

```js
    namespace MyApp.Services {
        
        public abstract class AsyncCrudAppServiceEx<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput>
            : AsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput>
            where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
            where TEntityDto : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
            where TGetAllInput : IPagedAndSortedResultRequest, ISearchable, IHasDefaultSorting
            where TUpdateInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
            where TGetInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>,
            ISearchService<TGetAllInput> {

            protected AsyncCrudAppServiceEx(IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> repository) : base(repository) { }

            [HttpGet]
            public virtual async Task<PagedResultDto<dynamic>> SearchGetAsync(TGetAllInput input) {
                return await SearchAsync(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public virtual async Task<PagedResultDto<dynamic>> SearchPostAsync(TGetAllInput input) {
                return await SearchAsync(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            
            public virtual async Task<PagedResultDto<dynamic>> SearchAsync(TGetAllInput input) {
            
                CheckGetAllPermission();
                CheckGetPermission();
            
                var iqueryable = this.Repository.GetAll();
            
                var builder = new PredicateStringBuilder<TGetAllInput>(input);
                var (WhereString, WhereArgs, SelectString, SortingString) = builder.Build();
            
                if (WhereString != null && WhereArgs != null) {
                    iqueryable = iqueryable
                        .Where(LyncDynamicParsingConfig, WhereString, WhereArgs);
                }
            
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SortingString)) {
                    iqueryable =
                        iqueryable
                        .OrderBy(LyncDynamicParsingConfig, SortingString);
                }
            
                List<dynamic> list = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectString)
                    ? await iqueryable
                        .Skip(input.SkipCount)
                        .Take(input.MaxResultCount)
                        .ToDynamicListAsync<dynamic>()
                        .ConfigureAwait(false)
                    : await iqueryable
                        .Skip(input.SkipCount)
                        .Take(input.MaxResultCount)
                        .Select(SelectString)
                        .ToDynamicListAsync<dynamic>()
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
            
                var dtoList = new PagedResultDto<dynamic>(
                        totalCount: list?.Count ?? 0,
                        items: list);
            
                return dtoList;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: а можно как-то ужать пример кода? чтобы получился [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy я бы с удовольствием, но для этого пришлось бы почти весь репозиторий с GitHub'а тянуть, т.к. была проблема с пониманием того, где закралась ошибка. Поэтому пытался объяснить подробно так, как только можно.

Comment: Ну если у тебя проблема в трех классах, тебе не нужно их полностью тянуть. Тебе даже реализация методов в них не нужна, нужны просто сами классы которые как-то наследуют и реализуют интерфейсы.

Comment: @Grundy предполагал, что из-за универсальности интерфейсов и классов где-то был доступ к свойству, который не был указан в интерфейсах, поэтому и выложил весь код, который использовался. Ну а в чём была проблема выяснилось только сейчас.

Comment: Если бы был доступ к свойству, которое не указано в интерфейсе, то ошибка была бы  именно об этом.

Comment: Обсуждение https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89872/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же сами указали

```
where TGetInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>, ISearchService<TGetAllInput>
```

То есть, по вашему, `TGetInput` должен реализовывать `ISearchService<TGetAllInput>`, что, по сути, неверно, вам этот интерфкйс нужен на самом классе, а не на параметре типа.

Видимо, вам надо было сделать как то так:

```
public abstract class AsyncCrudAppServiceEx<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput>
            : AsyncCrudAppService<TEntity, TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput, TGetInput>, ISearchService<TGetAllInput>
            where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
            where TEntityDto : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
            where TGetAllInput : IPagedAndSortedResultRequest, ISearchable, IHasDefaultSorting
            where TUpdateInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
            where TGetInput : IEntityDto<TPrimaryKey>
{....}
```

Comment: Привет! Не мог бы ты уделить не много времени? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89872/

Comment: @XelaNimed к сожалению, на работе не могу в чат, всё заблочено для меня, ни чат, ни картинки не вижу на сайте